# In music, what does it mean to "funkify"?

Tags: jazz, funk

I have heard the term used as "I funkified their album".  I assume that funkifying means making something more funky, but I was wondering if there is a more technical or at least genre-specific description.  Listening to Deodato as I write this.

Comment: If you're listening to Deodato, then compare his version of Also Sprach Zarathustra with the one from 2001: A Space Odyssey. The difference is the 'funkification' [a word I just made up;)

Comment: LIES https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/funkification ( https://www.theonion.com/national-funk-congress-deadlocked-on-get-up-get-down-is-1819565355 )